# Are there 200 billion lines of COBOL in production in 2019?

Tags: computers

Cited in [this article from ZDNet](https://www-zdnet-com.cdn.ampproject.org/c/s/www.zdnet.com/google-amp/article/cobol-turns-60-why-it-will-outlive-us-all/),

> According to a COBOL consulting company, which goes by the delightful name, COBOL Cowboys, **200 billion lines of COBOL code are still in use today** and that 90% of Fortune 500 companies still having COBOL code keeping the lights on.

Are there 200 billion lines of COBOL in production?